# Error on creating EXTERNAL_ACCESS assembly on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, .net-assembly

I am trying to create an assembly with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS permission, but when I run the CREATE ASSEMBLY line, it gives me

```
Msg 6585, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Could not impersonate the client during assembly file operation.
```

I'm using a strong-named dll, and have created the asymmetric key on the server, made sure my account has all the proper permissions, but I just keep getting that message. What could be causing this, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going through the wizard to create an assembly (which I hadn't realized existed) and that worked properly.

Comment: This worked for me too - to get to it, in the Object Explorer go under the database, in the Programmability/Assemblies (right click "New Assembly").